# How to display Rate module widget by php

Tags: 7, rating

I'm using the Page Manager (Panel) to customize the node layout, and the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module to rate them.

How to print the rating widget of the current node using php ?

I've tried to use [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1069906) code but no result.

```
<?php  print rate_embed($node, 'page_rating', RATE_FULL);  ?>
```

Comment: resolved `<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ($node = node_load(arg(1)))) {
  print rate_embed($node, 'NAME');
}
?>`

Answer (score 1):

print $node->rate_NAME['#markup'];

Replace NAME by the widget's machine readable name.

Answer (score 1):

**print rate_embed($node, 'plus1', RATE_FULL);**

Here, first parameter(**$node**) is the entity where you want to vote
'**plus1**' is the type of widget that you want to add
**RATE_FULL** is the display type of widget . Either it can be full or mini.

Try by passing $node =node_load(10). Where 10 is id of some node that exists in the site

Hope it will help